# Real time audio web to desktop application

Tags: javascript, c#, audio, stream, real-time

i´m trying to send real time audio messages from a web site to a desktop applicacion (C#) .Its for a public address system, so desktop applicacion just recives audio stream  and plays it through the speakers.

it's posible? what can I use for that purpose?

WebRTC can be used for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC used for browser based peer to peer communication. As per your requirement you can use WebRTC for real time audio messaging and can use [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)  for user desktop app.Other approach would be can use Socket.IO for RTC for audio messaging.